# How to programmatically add object to object where the key is the same?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am working with [underscore-query](https://github.com/davidgtonge/underscore-query) which requires a JSON object passed in to define all the search clauses. I need to build up the object via a loop which is reading the search values from an interface. I am at the point where I am getting all the search values, but I need to convert them to the query clause format. Here is a sample loop:

```
var filterArray = [];
var filterObject = {};
for (var key in $scope.mpsfilters) {
    if ($scope.mpsfilters.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        var keyparts = key.split('_');
        filterArray.push({
            $and: {
                "attribute_id": keyparts[0],
                "type": keyparts[1],
                "display_value": {$lte: $scope.mpsfilters[key].range_top, $gte: $scope.mpsfilters[key].range_bottom}
            }
        });
    }
}

for (var i = 0; i < filterArray.length; i++) {
    var filterStep = jQuery.extend({},filterObject, filterArray[i]);
    filterObject = filterStep;
}
```

The final result I need should look like this:

```
{
    $and: {
        "attribute_id": 2422, 
        "type": "max", 
        "display_value": {
            $lte: 200, 
            $gte: 0.3
        }
    },
    $and: {
        "attribute_id": 2421, 
        "type": "typ", 
        "display_value": {
            $lte: 150, 
            $gte: 50
        }
    }
    $and: {
        "attribute_id": 2750, 
        "type": "min", 
        "display_value": {
            $lte: 17, 
            $gte: 2
        }
    }
}
```

I've got two problems that make this complicated:

1. All the examples of using jQuery.extend(), angular.extend(), [angular.merge()](https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.0-rc.0/docs/api/ng/function/angular.merge), etc. only combine two objects into one and both are assigned known variables. In my case it needs to be dynamic because the amount of search variables can vary.
2. Each object I add to the main object basically has the same key "$and". The extend() and merge() (merge is new to Angular 1.4 and it preserves nested objects) functions will just update the same key unless you pass an empty {} object as the first argument. The filtering function this final object will get passed into *needs* to be in the structure I showed above.

The result of my code right now is like this:

```
{
    $and: {
        "attribute_id": 2750, 
        "type": "min", 
        "display_value": {
            $lte: 17, 
            $gte: 2
        }
    }
}
```

It seems to be replacing rather than appending. How can I get it to append?

Comment: you final result is invalid JS and can't be produced with an object, though you can make invalid JSON that sort of looks like it. in short, object keys in JS must be unique; use an array if you have >1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your current query as written will always return false. In the absence of a combining modifier, the "and" is always assumed (according to the docs). So you are looking for an object where the `attribute_id` is 2422 *and* 2421 *and* 2750.

That's logically impossible, so I assume you meant something like the following (even though this would still be invalid):

```
{ 
    $or: {
        $and: {
            "attribute_id": 2422, 
            "type": "max", 
            "display_value": {
                $lte: 200, 
                $gte: 0.3
            }
        },
        $and: {
            "attribute_id": 2421, 
            "type": "typ", 
            "display_value": {
                $lte: 150, 
                $gte: 50
            }
        }
        $and: {
            "attribute_id": 2750, 
            "type": "min", 
            "display_value": {
                $lte: 17, 
                $gte: 2
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Turns out that, even though the documentation never says so, the code actually does support arrays:

```js
var models = [
  { x: 0, y: 0 },
  { x: 0, y: 1 },
  { x: 0, y: 2 },
  { x: 0, y: 3 },
  { x: 1, y: 0 },
  { x: 1, y: 1 },
  { x: 1, y: 2 },
  { x: 1, y: 3 }
];

var result = _.query( models, {
    $or: [
      { $and: { x: 0, y: 1 } },
      { $and: { x: 1, y: 0 } }
    ]
});

console.log( result );
// result = [ { x: 0, y: 0 }, { x: 1, y: 0 } ]
```

```html
<!-- No CDN for underscore-query -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
<script>(function(){var e,t,r,n,u,a,s,i,o,c,l,f,y,h,p,$,d,g,m,k,v,b,w,O,x,q,j=[].slice,E=[].indexOf||function(e){for(var t=0,r=this.length;r>t;t++)if(t in this&&this[t]===e)return t;return-1},A={}.hasOwnProperty;for($=this,w={},b=function(){var e;return e={},["every","some","filter","reduce","map"].forEach(function(t){return e[t]=function(){var e,r;return r=arguments[0],e=2<=arguments.length?j.call(arguments,1):[],r[t].apply(r,e)}}),e.keys=Object.keys,e.isArray=Array.isArray,e.result=function(e,t){return null==e&&(e={}),"Function"===w.getType(e[t])?e[t]():e[t]},e.detect=function(e,t){var r,n,u;for(n=0,u=e.length;u>n;n++)if(r=e[n],t(r))return r},e.reject=function(e,t){var r,n,u,a;for(a=[],n=0,u=e.length;u>n;n++)r=e[n],t(r)||a.push(r);return a},e.intersection=function(e,t){var r,n,u,a;for(a=[],n=0,u=e.length;u>n;n++)r=e[n],-1!==t.indexOf(r)&&a.push(r);return a},e.isEqual=function(e,t){return JSON.stringify(e)===JSON.stringify(t)},e},n=function(e){var t,r,n,u;for(u=["every","some","filter","detect","reject","reduce","intersection","isEqual","keys","isArray","result","map"],r=0,n=u.length;n>r;r++)if(t=u[r],w[t]=e[t],!w[t])throw new Error(""+t+" missing. Please ensure that you first initialize underscore-query with either lodash or underscore")},w.getType=function(e){var t;return t=Object.prototype.toString.call(e).substr(8),t.substr(0,t.length-1)},w.makeObj=function(e,t){var r;return(r={})[e]=t,r},w.reverseString=function(e){return e.toLowerCase().split("").reverse().join("")},w.compoundKeys=["$and","$not","$or","$nor"],w.makeGetter=function(e){return e=e.split("."),function(t){var r,n,u,a;for(n=t,u=0,a=e.length;a>u;u++)r=e[u],n&&(n=w.result(n,r));return n}},o=function(e,t){var r,n,u;u=[];for(r in t)n=t[r],u.push(w.makeObj(e,w.makeObj(r,n)));return u},l=function(e){var t,r,n,u,a,s;switch(t=w.keys(e)[0],u=e[t],r={key:t},(null!=u?u.$boost:void 0)&&(r.boost=u.$boost,delete u.$boost),-1!==t.indexOf(".")&&(r.getter=w.makeGetter(t)),n=w.getType(u)){case"RegExp":case"Date":r.type="$"+n.toLowerCase(),r.value=u;break;case"Object":if(E.call(w.compoundKeys,t)>=0)r.type=t,r.value=y(u),r.key=null;else if(w.keys(u).length>1)r.type="$and",r.value=y(o(t,u)),r.key=null;else for(a in u)if(A.call(u,a)){if(s=u[a],!v(a,s))throw new Error("Query value ("+s+") doesn't match query type: ("+a+")");switch(r.type=a,a){case"$elemMatch":r.value=m(f(s));break;case"$endsWith":r.value=w.reverseString(s);break;case"$likeI":case"$startsWith":r.value=s.toLowerCase();break;case"$not":case"$nor":case"$or":case"$and":r.value=y(w.makeObj(r.key,s)),r.key=null;break;case"$computed":r=l(w.makeObj(t,s)),r.getter=w.makeGetter(t);break;default:r.value=s}}break;default:r.type="$equal",r.value=u}return"$equal"!==r.type||"Object"!==n&&"Array"!==n||(r.type="$deepEqual"),r},y=function(e){var t,r,n,u,a,s,i;for(n=w.isArray(e)?e:function(){var r;r=[];for(t in e)A.call(e,t)&&(u=e[t],r.push(w.makeObj(t,u)));return r}(),i=[],a=0,s=n.length;s>a;a++)r=n[a],i.push(l(r));return i},v=function(e,t){var r;switch(r=w.getType(t),e){case"$in":case"$nin":case"$all":case"$any":return"Array"===r;case"$size":return"Number"===r;case"$regex":case"$regexp":return"RegExp"===r;case"$like":case"$likeI":return"String"===r;case"$between":case"$mod":return"Array"===r&&2===t.length;case"$cb":return"Function"===r;default:return!0}},k=function(e,t){var r;switch(r=w.getType(t),e){case"$like":case"$likeI":case"$regex":case"$startsWith":case"$endsWith":return"String"===r;case"$contains":case"$all":case"$any":case"$elemMatch":return"Array"===r;case"$size":return"String"===r||"Array"===r;case"$in":case"$nin":return null!=t;default:return!0}},h=function(e,t,r,n,u){switch(e){case"$equal":return w.isArray(r)?E.call(r,t)>=0:r===t;case"$deepEqual":return w.isEqual(r,t);case"$contains":return E.call(r,t)>=0;case"$ne":return r!==t;case"$lt":return t>r;case"$gt":return r>t;case"$lte":return t>=r;case"$gte":return r>=t;case"$between":return t[0]<r&&r<t[1];case"$betweene":return t[0]<=r&&r<=t[1];case"$in":return E.call(t,r)>=0;case"$nin":return E.call(t,r)<0;case"$all":return w.every(t,function(e){return E.call(r,e)>=0});case"$any":return w.some(r,function(e){return E.call(t,e)>=0});case"$size":return r.length===t;case"$exists":case"$has":return null!=r===t;case"$like":return-1!==r.indexOf(t);case"$likeI":return-1!==r.toLowerCase().indexOf(t);case"$startsWith":return 0===r.toLowerCase().indexOf(t);case"$endsWith":return 0===w.reverseString(r).indexOf(t);case"$type":return typeof r===t;case"$regex":case"$regexp":return t.test(r);case"$cb":return t.call(n,r);case"$mod":return r%t[0]===t[1];case"$elemMatch":return d(r,t,null,!0);case"$and":case"$or":case"$nor":case"$not":return p(e,t,u,n);default:return!1}},m=function(e,t,r){var n,u;if("String"===w.getType(t)&&(n=t,t=function(e,t){return e[n](t)}),r){if(1!==e.length)throw new Error("score operations currently don't work on compound queries");if(u=e[0],"$and"!==u.type)throw new Error("score operations only work on $and queries (not "+u.type);return function(e){return e._score=p(u.type,u.parsedQuery,t,e,!0),e}}return function(n){var a,s;for(a=0,s=e.length;s>a;a++)if(u=e[a],!p(u.type,u.parsedQuery,t,n,r))return!1;return!0}},p=function(e,t,r,n,u){var a,s,i,o,c,l,f,y,p,$;for(i=0,c=0,l=1/t.length,y=0,p=t.length;p>y;y++)switch(o=t[y],a=o.getter?o.getter(n,o.key):r?r(n,o.key):n[o.key],f=k(o.type,a),f&&(f=h(o.type,o.value,a,n,r)),f&&(i++,u&&(s=null!=($=o.boost)?$:1,c+=l*s)),e){case"$and":if(!u&&!f)return!1;break;case"$not":if(f)return!1;break;case"$or":if(f)return!0;break;case"$nor":if(f)return!1;break;default:throw new Error("Invalid compound method")}return u?c:"$not"===e?0===i:"$or"!==e},f=function(e){var t,r,n,u,a;if(n=w.keys(e),!n.length)return[];if(t=w.intersection(w.compoundKeys,n),0===t.length)return[{type:"$and",parsedQuery:y(e)}];if(t.length!==n.length){E.call(t,"$and")<0&&(e.$and={},t.unshift("$and"));for(r in e)A.call(e,r)&&(a=e[r],E.call(w.compoundKeys,r)<0&&(e.$and[r]=a,delete e[r]))}return function(){var r,n,a;for(a=[],r=0,n=t.length;n>r;r++)u=t[r],a.push({type:u,parsedQuery:y(e[u])});return a}()},c=function(e){var t;return"String"===w.getType(e)&&(t=e,e=function(e,r){return e[t](r)}),e},e=function(){function e(e,t){this.items=e,this._getter=t,this.theQuery={}}return e.prototype.all=function(e,t){return e&&(this.items=e),e=this.indexes?this.getIndexedItems(this.items):this.items,d(e,this.theQuery,this._getter,t)},e.prototype.chain=function(){return _.chain(this.all.apply(this,arguments))},e.prototype.tester=function(){return i(this.theQuery,this._getter)},e.prototype.first=function(e){return this.all(e,!0)},e.prototype.getter=function(e){return this._getter=e,this},e}(),t=function(e){return function(t,r){var n;return r&&(t=w.makeObj(t,r)),null==(n=this.theQuery)[e]&&(n[e]=[]),this.theQuery[e].push(t),this}},q=w.compoundKeys,O=0,x=q.length;x>O;O++)s=q[O],e.prototype[s.substr(1)]=t(s);return e.prototype.find=e.prototype.query=e.prototype.run=e.prototype.all,r=function(t,r){return new e(t,r)},i=function(e,t){return m(f(e),c(t))},a=function(e,t,r){return d(e,t,r,!0)},d=function(e,t,n,u,a){var s;return arguments.length<2?r.apply(this,arguments):(n&&(n=c(n)),"Function"!==w.getType(t)&&(t=m(f(t),n,a)),(s=a?w.map:u?w.detect:w.filter)(e,t))},g=function(e,t,r){return d(e,t,r,!1,!0)},d.build=r,d.parse=f,d.findOne=d.first=a,d.score=g,d.tester=d.testWith=i,d.getter=d.pluckWith=w.makeGetter,u=function(e,t){return null==t&&(t=!0),e||(e=b(),t=!1),n(e),t&&e.mixin({query:d,q:d}),d},$._?u($._):exports&&("undefined"!=typeof module&&null!==module?module.exports:void 0)?module.exports=u:u}).call(this);</script>
```

So you can actually write your query like so:

```
{ 
    $or: [
        { $and: {
            "attribute_id": 2422, 
            "type": "max", 
            "display_value": {
                $lte: 200, 
                $gte: 0.3
            }
        } },
        { $and: {
            "attribute_id": 2421, 
            "type": "typ", 
            "display_value": {
                $lte: 150, 
                $gte: 50
            }
        } },
        { $and: {
            "attribute_id": 2750, 
            "type": "min", 
            "display_value": {
                $lte: 17, 
                $gte: 2
            }
        } }
    ]
}
```

Which would make your function *much* simpler:

```
var filterArray = [];
var filterObject = {};
for (var key in $scope.mpsfilters) {
    if ($scope.mpsfilters.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        var keyparts = key.split('_');
        filterArray.push({ $and: {
            "attribute_id": keyparts[0],
            "type": keyparts[1],
            "display_value": {$lte: $scope.mpsfilters[key].range_top, $gte: $scope.mpsfilters[key].range_bottom}
        }});
    }
}

// look how much easier this is!
filterObject = { $or: filterArray };
```

Comment: Unfortunately, arrays won't work. I'm using an add-on to Underscore.js called [underscore-query](https://github.com/davidgtonge/underscore-query). So far, the only way to filter all results with all the query variables being considered was to send in multiple `$and` objects at once.

Comment: @claywhipkey - That would have been helpful information in your original question.

Comment: Why not simply an array of `$and` objects? `[$and, $and, $and]`

Comment: @willlma - because that syntax is invalid?

Comment: @claywhipkey - After reading the source code, turns out arrays *will* work. They are not documented, but they work just fine. You can run the snippet to see a working example.

Comment: I'm not sure the updated version would get the right result, either. In my application I have ensured that every item has the same number of attributes with the same IDs. When I run the query I need to make sure that each attribute filter is considered. i.e. Every item has attribute 2422 and 2421. I need attribute 2421 to fit the range given AND I need 2422 to fit that range, too. I can't have it be an OR clause. 1/2

Comment: 2/2 I ended up going a different method (because I realized that I should have a non-visible value for searching that is separate than the display value), but I am going to mark your answer as correct because it is applicable to the original question.

Answer (score 0):

For posterity, here is my solution. I found some issues with using the display value. Instead I created a special property used only for filtering. In my service I do this:

```
var newPAD = {};
newPAD.attribute_id = attrib.realid;
newPAD.type = attrib.type;
if (typeof currentPAD !== 'undefined') { // it will be undefined if the part does not have data for it
    newPAD.display_value = currentPAD['value_' + attrib.type];
    Object.defineProperty(newPAD, attrib.id + "_search_value", {
        value: currentPAD['value_' + attrib.type],
        writable: true,
        enumerable: true,
        configurable: true});
} else {
    //set default value
    newPAD.display_value = '-';
    // creating a default value so the search can still work if no value is present
    // setting default to top value so they will only be excluded if this filter is explicitly changed
    Object.defineProperty(newPAD, attrib.id + "_search_value", {
        value: attrib.range_top,
        writable: true,
        enumerable: true,
        configurable: true});
}
```

Then when I apply the filter I do this:

```
var totalAttributes = _.size($scope.mpsfilters);
var filtered = _.filter(controller.parts, function (obj) {
    var passing = 0;
    for (var key in $scope.mpsfilters) {
        if ($scope.mpsfilters.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            var keyname = key + '_search_value';
            var paKey = controller.findKey(obj.paValues, keyname);
            var paValue = obj.paValues[paKey][keyname];
            if (paValue >= $scope.mpsfilters[key].range_bottom && paValue <= $scope.mpsfilters[key].range_top) {
                passing++;
            }
        }
    }
    return passing === totalAttributes;
});
```

This method works and underscore-query is no longer necessary.